# Quit OSX Terminal on Last Window Close

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, terminal.app

I have my preferences set so that `CTRL-D` closes my current window, but I'd like the Terminal application to quit if I close my last/only terminal window. iTerm2 can do this. Can Terminal do it?

Answer (score 0):

open applescript editor and paste in

```
on is_running(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running

set app to "Terminal"

repeat
    if is_running(app) then
        tell application app
            set WindowNum to get window count
            if WindowNum = 0 then
                quit
            end if
        end tell
        delay 5
    end if
end repeat
```

Then save the script and run it by double-clicking it.

Comment: You can get this to work for most programs.

Comment: How is this easier than quitting Terminal.app manually with the mouse or with Command-Q ? I think that is an implicit requirement in the OP.